# how do a do a scroll in to view for a newly added list item in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vueJS to build a task view applicatioon

when I add a new task I want the div that contains the list to immediately focus on the newly added list item

below is my html in the template for the list of task

```
<ul>
  <li
          v-for="task in filteredTasks"
          :key="task.id"
          id="taskListItem"
          ref="taskListItem"
          class="taskList d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
        >
        <span> {{ task.name }} </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

below is my functions in computed and methods to add and filter out tasks

script

```
 computed : {
   filteredTasks() {
      return this.selectedUsers.length
        ? this.filteredOnProgress.filter((task) =>
            task.userIds.some((id) => this.selectedUsers.includes(id))
          )
        : this.filteredOnProgress;
    },
}

methods : {
    addTaskName(){
      if (this.newTaskName.name != "") {
      this.addTask(this.newTaskName)
      this.newTaskName.name = ""
      }
     }
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve my problem like this

I gave my unordered list an id="taskListul"

and in methods I added a function:

```
  scrollToEndOfTask() {
      const taskScroll = this.$el.querySelector("#taskListul")
      const scrollHeight = taskScroll.scrollHeight
      taskScroll.scrollTop = scrollHeight
    },
```

I called this function in update method of the vue instance

```
updated() {
    this.scrollToEndOfTask()
  },
```